# Problem dealing with deleted records in a foxpro dbf file

Tags: python, foxpro, dbf

I get always the following message :

> is_deleted() is not defined

This is my python program.
What am i doing wrong?

```
import dbf

tableDirsync = dbf.Table("o:/python/dirsync.dbf")
tableDirsync.open()

for dirsync in tableDirsync:
    if is_deleted(dirsync):
        continue
    else:  
        print(dirsync.diri1, dirsync.diro1)

tableDirsync.close()
mainloop()
```

Comment: your code is referring to a function called `is_deleted` and it doesn't exist!  you need to figure out where this function has gone.  failing that you need to figure out what it did and write your own version

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the phyton dbf package (see [enter link description here](https://pythonhosted.org/dbf/):)

```
Check if a record has been marked as deleted:
        record = table[1] # for example
        if record.has_been_deleted:
            print "table.pack() will physically remove this record! (and all other deleted records)"
```

so in your case:

```
import dbf

tableDirsync = dbf.Table("o:/python/dirsync.dbf")
tableDirsync.open()

for dirsync in tableDirsync:
    if dirsync.has_been_deleted:
        continue
    else:  
        print(dirsync.diri1, dirsync.diro1)

tableDirsync.close()
mainloop()
```

Comment: That method i have already tried, then i get the folowing message :

dbf.FieldMissingError: 'has_been_deleted:  no such field in table'

I am running python 3.7

Comment: I'm not into phyton but have you tried *dirsync.has_been_deleted()* instead ?